# Not a valid month TO_DATE(inputMONYYYY, 'DD-MM-YYYY)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

`I've to accept input as Month name and year and validate condition with date formatted as ‘DD-MM-YYY’.

This is my stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_REPORT (
   v_customer_id   IN              NUMBER,
   v_user_id       IN              VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   monthYear       IN              VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   solutionType    IN              VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   customerAccNo   IN              VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   productType     IN              VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   output          OUT             SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
        selectclause    CLOB;
       whereclause     CLOB;
       startDate          CLOB;
   BEGIN
         whereclause := ' where 1=1';
      startDate := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(monthYear,'MON YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
           
      IF monthYear IS NOT NULL THEN
           whereclause := whereclause
                          || ‘ and sm.activation_date >= ’
                          || startDate;
           END IF;               
           selectclause := 'select * from customer_master cm
                               inner join sim_master sm on sm.customer_id = cm.customer_id
                               inner join solution_type st on st.id_key = cm.solution_type ' || whereclause;
           dbms_output.put_line(selectclause);
       OPEN output FOR selectclause;
   END;
END PROC_REPORT;
```

This gives error “not a valid month”. When I hard code monthYear as below, it works well:

`startDate := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('JAN 2023','MON YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');`

I've tried converting monthYear to char as:
`startDate := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(monthYear),'MON YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');`

Please help me understand what am I missing.`

Comment: Post the way you **call** that procedure, so that we'd see which values you pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need dynamic SQL and can use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_REPORT (
   v_customer_id   IN  NUMBER,
   v_user_id       IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   monthYear       IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   solutionType    IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   customerAccNo   IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   productType     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
   output          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN output FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   customer_master cm
           inner join sim_master sm on sm.customer_id = cm.customer_id
           inner join solution_type st on st.id_key = cm.solution_type
    WHERE  (  monthYear IS NULL
           OR sm.activation_date >= TO_DATE(monthYear,'MON YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English')
           );
END PROC_REPORT;
/
```

I assume that `activation_date` is a `DATE` column; in which case you want to perform the comparison as `DATE`s (and not as formatted strings, so you do not want to convert back to a string).